# Filtrar un objeto con coincidencias JavaScript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

compañer@s.

Estoy intentado aplicar filtros para mostrar ciertos datos con JavaScript, para no filtrar con MySQL y ejecutar varias peticiones. He utilizado el método `filter()` para hacer esto con los datos que son 'fijos'; con esto me refiero a que deben ser datos que en MySQL, si quisiera hacer lo mismo, usaría `columna = 'valor'`. Lo que deseo, es algo similar a `columna LIKE '%valor%'`, pero con **JavaScript**.

Pongo cómo lo he hecho hasta ahora:

```js
readResults() {
  axios.post(this.route + 'receivers/receptionResults.php', {
    typeFunction: 'readResultList'
  }).then(response => {
    if (this.filterListResults.resultName != "") {
      //
    }

    if (this.filterListResults.investigatorName != "") {
      //
    }

    if (this.filterListResults.sgpsResult) {
      this.resultList = response.data.filter(data => data.sgps_proyecto == this.filterListResults.sgpsResult)
    }

    if (this.filterListResults.trlResult) {
      this.resultList = response.data.filter(data => data.trl_proyecto == this.filterListResults.trlResult)
    }

    if (this.filterListResults.regionalResult) {
      this.resultList = response.data.filter(data => data.id_regional == this.filterListResults.regionalResult)
    }

    if (this.filterListResults.resultName == "" && this.filterListResults.investigatorName == "" && this.filterListResults.sgpsResult == "" && this.filterListResults.trlResult == "" && this.filterListResults.regionalResult == "") {
      this.resultList = this.resultList.splice(1);
      this.resultList[0] = null;
    }
  });
},
```

Las 2 líneas de comentario (`//`), es donde se debería aplicar el filtro que deseo y sólo para esos 2 casos. Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Lo puedes hacer con [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: Lo he intentado, pero me dice que .includes no es una función.

Comment: No. Es un objeto. Es una consulta a una base de datos.

Comment: Sí. Me arroja este error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined

Comment: Bueno, se lo estarás aplicando a algo que no está definido. No conozco la estructura de datos como para ayudarte con eso. Si agregas un ejemplo de la respuesta de la base de datos puedo hacerte un snippet. Mientras tanto hice un ejemplo para que entiendas a lo que me refiero [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-bush-l2zfm?file=/src/main.js)

Comment: Ya pude. Muchísimas gracias por tu ejemplo. Quizás me hacía falta el toLowerCase()

Comment: El toLowerCase() es simplemente para que no sea sensitivo a mayúsculas/minúsculas

Comment: Pues, es lo único que no intenté. Y lo puse como en tu ejemplo y ya funcionó.

Answer (score 1):

Gracias al [ejemplo](https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-bush-l2zfm?file=/src/main.js) en los comentarios bajo la pregunta, pude resolverlo de la siguiente manera:

```
if (this.filterListResults.resultName != "") {
    this.resultList = response.data.filter(data => data.nombre_proyecto.toLowerCase().includes(this.filterListResults.resultName.toLowerCase()));
}
```